# Convergence of a sequence of subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Let $E_n\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a sequence of subspaces. What does it mean $E_n$ convergence to a subspace $E\subset \mathbb R^n$? I saw this when reading about [hyperbolic sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_set).

Where can I  read about this subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If all the subspaces have a common dimension $r$, then a natural object to look at is the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $Gr(r,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

In particular one may define a metric $d(E,F) = \|P_E - P_F\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm and $P_E \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to E$ is the orthogonal projection on $E$. The convergence of $E_n \to E$ can now be taken to mean that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(E_n, E) = 0$. One more concrete way of computing this metric is via the formula:
$$d(E,F) = \sup \{|\langle u,v \rangle| : u \in E, v \in F^\bot, \|u\| = \|v\| = 1\}$$

Comment: Thanks you. Could you please tell me where did you read about this? I want to read on references?

Comment: @mac: Unfortunately I don't remember where I learned this from but Grassmannians are quite standard stuff, so I'd expect a little googling should suffice. The formula in the end is something I proved in my master's thesis a few years ago, having found it used somewhere else without a proof. You could try to prove it too - it's not that hard.